# Understanding radiation mechanism of inset fed microstrip antenna

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-current, antennas

I have designed a simple inset-fed microstrip antenna, resonating at 2.45 GHz.
The transmission line model of the antenna reduces it to two radiating slots separated by a microstrip line, and it's precisely the surface current density in these slots that is responsible for radiation.

However, I encountered doubts when I simulated it to compare the behavior with the theoretical model. While the simulated surface current density in the upper and lower limits behaves as expected, the surface current density in the rest of the antenna, particularly the sides, is much greater. Why is this not considered in the model? Or why aren't the right and left sides taken as the slots since the current density is prominent there?

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you add some labels on the picture for ease of reference when discussing what you are asking about?

Comment: I am not very familiar with Ansys so I do not know how to include labels. But, as noted on the scale, what is plotted is the surface current density vector on the patch.

Comment: you seem to be saying that the antenna radiates from the "slots separated by a microstrip line", what are these slots you are referring to? you can add labels using your favorite image software that can process a png file.

Comment: I have added a rectangular microstrip antenna diagram from the book of Balanis, I hope that helps to see what I am talking about. In this book, the author states that the antenna is equivalent to those two radiating slots.

Comment: Excellent question! Notice how around #1 and #2 the currents are are out of phase and in the other two sides to which you are referring to having higher current density they are in phase. As a slot radiator it radiates through its "magnetic" surface current. Instead plotting the "electric" surface currents on the metal, try to plot the electric fields in the slots or the charge densities at the edges (electric currents generate H, electric charges generate E) and see the difference.

Comment: I have plotted the electric field and effectively, it is much stronger in the "slots".

However, I am still struggling to understand some points:
1) Why are the phase relations you mentioned important to understand why Jsurface
is not contributing to radiation?
2) In summary, each slot radiates through Msurface, which points in the z direction (see diagrams), and the same sense for both slots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two apertures (you called them slots) radiating, these are fed approximately $\lambda_g/2$ apart therefore the charges on the metal that induce the electric fields parallel with the aperture and perpendicular to the metal are in the opposite direction. These do not radiate perpendicular to the patch. But there is also a pair of fringing fields whose components parallel with the patch are actually pointing in the *same* direction along the "z" axis (in your diagram the "x" axis), and these are the fields shown in the plots taken from Orfanidis: Electromagnetic Waves and Antennas.
On the contrary, fringing fields of the apertures parallel with the feed line do not radiate in the "z" direction because the pairs are in opposite direction to each other.
[image]